# How do i make my drop down menu visible beyond the navbar?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, navbar

I'm trying to have a drop down menu within a navbar; however, it only displays until the limit of my navbar when, ideally, id like it to be "in front" of the navbar so to speak.

[Dropdown is cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vb7Q.png)

I am new to html and CSS so my exploration is somewhat limited. I have implemented one of bootstrap's navbar's and also used their dropdown button html. I expected this to work okay but, as stated, the dropdown seems to be bound within the navbar (assuming this is because it is within the navbar div?) I have also attempted to follow w3schools guide but I didn't succeed with that either.

Sidenote: because of the limited visibility, the "my account" button logs the user out, this is intentional for now lmao.

```html
<body>      
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="logo" href="/"><img src="static/Logo_2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            {% if not session["id"] %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="login">Log In</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if session["id"] %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="languages">Languages</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="faq">FAQs</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Account
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="logout">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="logout">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% if get_flashed_messages() %}
        <header>
            <div class="alert alert-primary mb-0 text-center" role="alert">
                {{ get_flashed_messages() | join(" ") }}
            </div>
        </header>
    {% endif %}

    <main class="container-fluid py-5 text-center">
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </main>
</body>
```

```css
.navbar {
    height: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.navbar-nav {
    align-items: baseline;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    gap: 3em;
}


.nav-link {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
}


.nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
}


.btn-secondary {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: black
}


.btn-secondary:hover {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: red;
}


.logo {
    display: flex;
    scale: 0.4;
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

Comment: The nav bar style `overflow: hidden;` will, as you would expect, hide the overflow. Are you sure you need that rule?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the "overflow: hidden;" style from .navbar css, so your code should be-

```
.navbar {
    height: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your example should be cut down to just the minimum that displays the issue. you have extra classes, some ASP-like code, etc - none of that is needed and just makes it harder to diagnose.

the issue appears to be that your submenu is contained *inside* the top-level .navbar element, but you are constraining that to have a height of 100 (and you should include the metric here - 100px? 100cm?) with overflow being hidden. this means that the submenu gets cut off.

you could just remove those constraints.

a better solution would involve a rewrite, so the submenu items are positioned absolutely, in a relatively-positioned placeholder. there are examples of this online. example: https://gist.github.com/SamWM/901853

Comment: Thanks for this, I've updated my example to something that I think matches what you said about being more concise and removed some of the Jinja syntax - does this still need refining for other viewers? Just wondering as I'd like to use Stack Overflow more but don't want to be guilty of poor practice lol. Removing overflow: hidden worked a charm and once the timer is up I'll mark this as correct and will be sure to check out the resource you linked. Appreciate the help!

Comment: don't worry about being perfect. just improve a little each time. your example is much more readable now. I hope my answer was useful to you. good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 0):

{% if not session["id"] %}
                    Log In
                {% endif %}
                {% if session["id"] %}
                    Languages
                    FAQs
                    
                        
                          Account

My Account

Log Out

{% endif %}
            
            
        
        ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).